# box2d как уничтожить динамический объект

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, box2d

Тело1 при столкновении с телом2, должен уничтожаться, из того, что я нашел:

```
ball.ballBody.setActive(false);
        world.destroyBody(ball.ballBody);
```

Ошибка :
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x3f80000c (code=1), thread 22959 (Thread-471)
08-11 16:55:21.083 1455-1873/system_process E/NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report
                                                                   libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
                                                                       at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
                                                                       at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:128)
                                                                       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:149)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)

Comment: ball- класс actor,  в нем создается body-ballBody

Answer (score 0):

Коллизии происходят во время симуляции физики в "мире". В это время он находится в заблокированном состоянии и разрушать в нем тела нельзя. Измените параметры объекта так, чтобы он не участвовал в игровом процессе (переместите его в категорию "мертвых объектов", например). Сохраните ссылку на него в какой-нибудь список.

Когда симуляция физики закончится, обойдите этот список и разрушьте все тела из этого списка.